# Display multiple related Django models in a templates

Tags: mysql, django-models, django-views

Hi I am having the models.py  like this

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    book_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%d %s %s %s" % (self.book_id,self.book_name, self.author_name,self.publisher_name)


class Author(models.Model):
    author_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age=models.IntegerField()
    book=models.ForeignKey(Book)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d %s %s' % (self.author_id,self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

i waant to display these two tables in a single order in a html template.I am new to django..i am learning now..plz  help me with a design of views.py and an "htmlfile.html templates".Plz give me the procedure also

Comment: check your latest question for answer,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173251/retrieve-data-from-two-tables-with-foreign-
key-relationship-in-django

Answer (score 0):

check your latest question for answer,

[Retrieve data from two tables with foreign key relationship in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173251/retrieve-data-from-two-tables-with-foreign-)
key-relationship-in-django