# Retrieve data from two tables with foreign key relationship in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
  This is my models.py file 


 from django.db import models

   class Author(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        email = models.EmailField()
        age=models.IntegerField()

        class Meta:
        db_table=u'Author Info'

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u"%d %s %s %s" % (self.pk, self.name, self.author.name, self.publisher_name)

        def books(self):
            return Book.objects.filter(author=self)

    class Book(models.Model):
        book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
        publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
        author=models.ForeignKey(Author)

        class Meta:
            db_table = u'Book Name'

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%d %s %s' % (self.pk, self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

I want to diaplay the datas from 2 tables,in django.Please guide me how to write views.py and templates.i am using foreign key in author table

Comment: this is your question earlier

Comment: This is all very clearly explained in the tutorial. What problems are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Following views and html is used for display all books with corrosponding author details.

views.py

```
def client_add(request):
   books = Book.objects.all()
   return render_to_response('book_details.html', locals(),    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

book_details.html

```
<body>
{% for book in books %}
{{book.book_name}}
{{book.publisher_name}}
{{book.author.first_name}}
{{book.author.last_name}}
{{book.author.email}}
{{book.author.age}}
{% endif %}
</body>
```

The Following views and html is used for display books for particular author corrosponding details.

views.py

```
def client_add(request):
   books = Book.objects.all(author_last_name ="author_last_name")
   return render_to_response('book_details.html', locals(),    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

book_details.html

```
<body>
{% for book in books %}
{{book.book_name}}
{{book.publisher_name}}
{{book.author.first_name}}
{{book.author.last_name}}
{{book.author.email}}
{{book.author.age}}
{% endif %}
</body>
```